# How to free JFrame resources?

Tags: java, swing

I have a question for you:
Calling `setVisible(false)` on a `JFrame`, makes it disapper, right?
Calling again `setVisible(true)` makes it appear again, this means that the object is completely still in RAM, right?
If I need to get rid of everything right after I press the "Close" button, what's the correct way (this `JFrame` is displayed when I press a "config" button in the main UI, so it should disappears (also from RAM) when I press the close button)?
Thanks for your time and sorry for my bad English

Comment: You may be looking for `CardLayout` or perhaps a dialog.

Comment: `dispose` will release the native resources held by the frame, releasing more memory, but, if you make the frame visible again, it will take longer, as it will need to recreate these resources. You can also affect the dispose method used by setting the `defaultCloseOperation`. In order to completely release the frame, you will need to dispose it (so with at least `defaultCloseOperation` set to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`) and remove all references to the frame and any of it's contents, including listeners

Comment: If you want to move to a new view, you should consider using `CardLayout`, if you want to collect some information from the user which will affect the current view, you should use a dialog. See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: I can't use a cardLayout because the main window is build with javaFX, and this option window is in swing, i think that dispose() is the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

playing with the visibility of the `JFrame` will not allow the OS to reclaim its native resources allocated by the window, a way for doing so is to call `JFrame#dispose`

```
/**
 * Releases all of the native screen resources used by this
 * {@code Window}, its subcomponents, and all of its owned
 * children. That is, the resources for these {@code Component}s
 * will be destroyed, any memory they consume will be returned to the
 * OS, and they will be marked as undisplayable.
 * ...
 */
public void dispose() {
    doDispose();
}
```

another way to invoke dispose on closing the JFrame is to do the following

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set default close operation of the frame.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

[See this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

You can also try to clean up after your frame has been closed/disposed.

Find the relevant [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html).

Comment: Will that will terminate the JVM, but `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` will cause the frame to release it's native resources, obviously, until you dereference the frame and it's contents, it won't be garbage collected. From the sounds of things, the OP wants to dispose of the frame so they can move to some other part of the program, but allow the frame to be garbage collected

Comment: That's interesting, then he may be looking for manual cleanup.

Comment: That's not the answer, EXIT_ON_CLOSE is equal to a System.exit(0), the whole program is killed, not just A frame

Comment: @MaProgrammer already pointed that out that's why I have given the second link for manual clean up.